# Python random number game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that will generate a random number between 1 and 100 and then ask the user for a guess. At that point if the guess is correct it will tell them so and vice-versa if it's wrong.

What I have so far is:

```
import random

def playGame2():
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Guess what it is: ")
    if str(number) == guess:
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        print("Nope, I was thinking of" +str(number))
```

When I run the program it just gives me `<function playGame2 at 0x0000000002D3D2F0>`.
Why is it doing that?

Comment: Sorry it didn't post the error it gave me. It was <function playGame2 at 0x0000000002D3D2F0>

Comment: The error is due to how the function is called, we need to see that code

Comment: I'm not having any trouble running this if I do `playGame2()` at the end. How are you calling your function?

Comment: @Mark: Who told you that `==` doesn't compare strings in Python? `assert "a" == "a" and str(2) == "2"`

Comment: When it has that <function playGame2 at 0x0000000002D3D2F0> it's a accessible object, but when you print it your not really using it to use it do, "playGame2()"

Comment: @abarnert - er too many lanugages - I messed that up

Comment: @Mark: `assert Python != Java` :)

Answer (score 8):

You have to execute the function, your output implies you did something like

```
print(playGame2)
```

instead of

```
playGame2()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def playGame2():
    number = random.randrange(1,100)
    guess = input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Guess what it is: ")
    if str(number) == guess:
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        print("Nope, I was thinking of %s" % number)
```

Try that. I just ran it worked fine. To use enter playGame2() in Idle or a place where you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell python this have a main function
try include this at the end of your code :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    playGame2()
```

and put this at the beginning :

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

at the top of your code, for the way of specifying the encoding of a Python file that you use. see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

wish it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


guess=99 

count=0  

no = random.randint(1,100)  


print("Welcome to the guessing game!")



while guess != no :  
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: ")) 

    if guess < no : 
        print("Higher") 
        count+=1  

    if guess > no :
        print("Lower") 
        count+=1  

    if (guess==no):
        print("You win, the number was indeed:",no)
        print("It took you a total of:",count,"tries")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random #import modules
import time

x = random.randint(1,100)#This is the random number

while True:
    try:
        while True: #Make a loop
            y = input('Enter a number: ')
            if int(y) == x:
                print('You won!')
                time.sleep(5)
                exit()
            if int(y) > x:
                print('The input is too high')
                continue #restart the loop
            if int(y) < x:
                print('The input is too low')
                continue
    except:
        print('Only numbers')
        continue
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).